# How can i create a path to files inside folders that are outside of "app" folder in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, file, url

For example, this is my file structure:

- MyProject

  - app
  - bootstrap
  - config
  - database
  - node_modules

    - pdfjs-dist

      - build

        - pdf.js
  - public

    - upload

      - documents

        - solution_12.pdf
  - resources

So when i type http://127.0.0.1:8000/uploads/documents/solution_12.pdf (1) into my web browser, it works fine, the web brower shows the pdf file. But when i type http://127.0.0.1:8000/node_modules/pdfjs-dist/build/pdf.js (2), i get not found error.
So can someone explain to my how does path in laravel works? How come the (1) link doesnt contain "public" route, (upload/documents/solution_12.pdf is stored inside public folder) but it still works? And why the (2) link returns not found?

Comment: You does not need to access node_modules in runtime - use mix or vite to compile you js.

Comment: Um im need the path so i can setup pdfjsLib.GlobalWorkerOptions.workerSrc

Comment: your webserver points your domain to your `/public` folder, anything outside of it can't be accessed as a file your web browser

Comment: You can do this - import your lib in boostrap, compile js with mix/vite and do anything you want. Read in the docs how compilers works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Laravel serves the whole application from public/index.php file, that means when you run `php artisan serve` or host on the server/cloud, you have to point your domain root to `/public`. so, the server can access all the files from the `public` folder. if you wish to access files from the `node_modules`, you have to add the file paths to your `laravel mix` or `vite` configuration and that will copy/compile them into the public folder.

For the best practices, the files should be uploaded in the `storage` folder and you can symlink it to the `public` folder by executing the `php artisan storage:link` command.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the answer. Can you tell me more about the vite part. I did a little reseach, and this is what i did:

At vite.config.js, inside defineConfig:

```
plugins: [
        laravel({
            input:
                [
                    'node_modules/pdfjs-dist/build/pdf.js'
                ],
            refresh: true,
        }),
    ],
```

Inside app.js, i import the pdf.js script:

```
import '../../node_modules/pdfjs-dist/build/pdf.js';
```

And to use this script, at my resources/views/instructor/course/edit.blade.php
I add:

```
<script src="node_modules/pdfjs-dist/build/pdf.js"></script>
```

But the console say that my pdfjsLib cant be found. WHat did i do wrong?

Comment: Please use this vite plugin to copy the files from node modules: https://www.npmjs.com/package/vite-plugin-static-copy

Ref: https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/vite/copying-assets-with-vite

Answer (score 0):

About the vite plugin, is there others step need to be proceeded? Cause I added this in my vite.config.js:

```
plugins: [
        viteStaticCopy({
            targets: [
                {
                    src: 'node_modules/pdfjs-dist/build/pdf.js',
                    dest: 'js/pdf.js'
                },
            ]
        }),
    ]
```

and then run npm dev build but i still get the error. Am i missing something?